# SSIS/DTS error when exporting multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Im getting a weird issue here that when I run the Import/Export from MSSMS 2008R2 and export these 4 tables to an access database with the same table structures that it will error with below:

> "- Copying to 'sdgrpmap' (Error) Messages Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow
>   Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
>
> An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)   Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow
>   Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.   The
>   "input "Destination Input" (144)" failed because error code 0xC020907B
>   occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Destination Input"
>   (144)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified
>   object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.
>
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)   Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow
>   Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.   The ProcessInput
>   method on component "Destination 2 - stdchp" (131) failed with error
>   code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (144). The
>   identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method.
>   The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and
>   will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure. 
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)"

Now I tried verifying the data is not an issue and verified that all the table mappings are correct and correct data types too but it still fails.

I narrowed it down by running each of the 4 table exports individually and each one worked just fine. But when I added all 4 back it failed again. I added 3 of the 4 and it still ran. The table "sdgrpmap" is the problem table when in the group of tables to export. Not sure why but googled all the error codes and they are wide ranging and not really on my issue.

Anyone know why one table would fail when run in a group of table exports but not by itself? Sounds like a locking or update issue and the access connection is set to shared but probably a sql server issue.

Thanks

Edit: Adding the report which shows that 3 tables wrote out the correct number of records but the 4th "stdchp" only wrote out 193 out of the 2622 records.

> - Executing (Success)
> - Copying to `chapterorigin` (Success) 16 rows transferred
> - Copying to `sdgrpmap` (Error) 40 rows transferred
>
> Messages Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80004005.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)   Error 0xc0209029:
>   Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Destination Input"
>   (144)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error
>   row disposition on "input "Destination Input" (144)" specifies failure
>   on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard) 
>   Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component
>   "Destination 2 - stdchp" (131) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while
>   processing input "Destination Input" (144). The identified component
>   returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific
>   to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow
>   task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)
>
> - Copying to `stdchp` (Stopped)
> - Copying to `stdpdrpanelmap` (Stopped)
> - Post-execute (Success) Messages
> - Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination - chapterorigin" (22)" wrote 16 rows. 
>     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Information 0x4004300b: Data
>     Flow Task 1: "component "Destination 1 - sdgrpmap" (66)" wrote 40
>     rows.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Information 0x4004300b:
>     Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination 2 - stdchp" (131)" wrote 193
>     rows.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Information 0x4004300b:
>     Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination 3 - stdpdrpanelmap" (201)"
>     wrote 4853 rows.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: Is there a database object named `stdchp`? If so, what's the DDL in SQL Server? The definition in MS Access?

Comment: Yes, thats one of the tables and the objects do exist and are named correctly in both source and destination. Case is correct too. Just tried rerunning it to a local access db as the destination and it writes out 3 tables ok but the last it only partially outputs. This is a bit different from when it was on a network share as it partially wrote out the 3rd table and the 4th was complete.

Comment: Remember that when I export out a single table at a time it works perfectly.

Comment: Do you have the SSIS saved or are you Import/Export-ing every time. Why not save the SSIS and set it up as a job and run the job instead of going through the wizard every time?

Comment: I have the SSIS saved but I recreate it each time as going back and forth adding/removing tables to figure htis out is simpiler. 

Looks like possibly the access database being a 97 version may have something to do with this. Was able to use a 2000 db and import some test data up to 100,000 records in 10 tables each and no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's failing because of data in tables.

If you are combining data from all four tables and putting in one table then destination table should support requirement for all 4 tables.

It's down to -

- Null values are allowed or not
- data types and field size

You can [implement re-direct bad rows](https://dbadiary.wordpress.com/tag/ssis-dts_e_inducedtransformfailureonerror/) logic in your package so that you can have bad data(if there is any). Also with the help of derived column, process null values.

Comment: No, the 4 sql tables are going to 4 separate access tables. When I run the export on a single table one at a time it succeeds so its not data. I even reviewed the data and querried to see any invalid characters etc but that is done before its imported into sql.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, it seems that its an access 97 issue as exporting to access 2000 works fine but we cannot use 2000 as consumers need 97 as per their programs requirements which cannot be changed at this time.